# изменение значения вложенных полей в json файле: генерация случайных значений по правилам

Tags: python, json

у меня есть json-файл, состоящий из двух структур: «A» и «D», структура «A» имеет три поля: B, C, G. Поле B является числом, поле C представляет собой список
[1,1,1], поле G является словом.
структура D имеет два поля E и F, каждое из которых является числом.

```
{
   "A": {
       "B": 0, 
       "C": [1,1,1],
       "G": "QWERTY"
   },
   "D": {
       "E": 2, 
       "F": 4
   }
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы моя программа прочитала этот json-файл и заполнила каждое поле случайным значением из определенного диапазона, выбрать значение надо рандомно. Каждое поле имеет **свой собственный диапазон значений**, которыми он может пользоваться.
Например, поле B может быть изменено в диапазоне от 0 до 5(это пример, диапазон может быть любой, главное, чтобы в этом диапазоне могло изменяться только значение поля B), то есть когда программа выполняется, значение в поле B может быть любым, от 0 до 5.
Поле C представляет собой список **со своим собственным, другим диапазоном значений, отличным от диапазона значений поля B.**
Поле C может варьироваться в диапазоне от 1 до 20(это тоже просто пример абстрактного диапазона, отличного от диапазона поля B). То есть, поле C, при выполнении программы будет принимать случайные значения из диапазона от 1 до 20, например:
[1,4,6] или [5,9,15] или [19,4,16].
поле G - это слово, значение поля G: «QWERTY», во время программы оно должно быть случайно заменено либо на «ASDFGHJ», либо остаться «QWERTY»- это уже как рандом выдаст.
у меня есть программа, но она делает совсем не то, что надо, моя программа в каждое поле записывает рандомное значение из одного и того же диапазона, от 0 до 100, и поле С, которое было списком, она делает просто константным одним значением.

```
import json
import random
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('newtest.json')
data =json.loads(path.read_text(encoding='utf-8'))
for firstKey, firstValue in data.items():
    for key, value in firstValue.items():
        firstValue[key] = random.randrange(0, 100)
    data[firstKey] = firstValue
path.write_text(json.dumps(data),encoding='utf-8')
```

Как сказать программе, что поле С было списком, и оно должно остаться списком, поле G было строкой, строкой оно и должно остаться, и что каждое поле должно изменяться в своем диапазоне?
Чтобы получилось примерно следущее

```
{
   "A": {
       "B": 1, 
       "C": [0,60,250],
       "G": "ASDFGHJ"
   },
   "D": {
       "E": 1, 
       "F": 0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы создал словарь с нужной структурой, где вместо значений хранятся функции генерирующие нужный результат:

```
from random import randint, choice

data_gen = {
   "A": {
       "B": lambda : randint(0,5), 
       "C": lambda : [randint(1, 20) for _ in xrange(3)],
       "G": lambda : choice(["QWERTY", "ASDFGHJ"]) }}
```

Формируем новый словарь:

```
new_data = {}

for key0 in data_gen:
    for key1 in data_gen[key0]:
        new_data.setdefault(key0, {})[key1] =  data_gen[key0][key1]()
```

Результат работы:

```
print new_data
# {'A': {'C': [1, 17, 3], 'B': 0, 'G': 'ASDFGHJ'}}
# {'A': {'C': [2, 12, 14], 'B': 5, 'G': 'QWERTY'}}
# {'A': {'C': [14, 3, 20], 'B': 3, 'G': 'ASDFGHJ'}}
```

Comment: в более общем случае (произвольная вложенность), можно по путям правила задавать: `rules = {('A', 'B'): lambda: randrange(6), ('D', 'E'): lambda: randrange(2)}`. Чтобы автоматически промежуточные словари создавать: [`reduce(lambda d,k: d.setdefault(k, {}), keys, dict_nested)[newkey] = newvalue`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11918852/4279)